# Defining a new variable from a string

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the string `myString` defined as follows:

```
var myString = "foo 123";
```

How could I define a new variable `numbers` from `myString` such that `numbers = 123`?

EDIT:  Here is a more precise procedure of how I'm looking for numbers to be defined.

1. If myString doesn't begin with "foo", then numbers = 0.
2. If myString does begin with "foo", then numbers should be the first number after "foo".  For example, if myString = "foo 12.3 14", then numbers should equal "12.3".

Comment: And what should happen with the string "foo 123 bar 456"? Or "123 foo"?

Comment: Sorry I have should have been more precise.  In the former case, numbers should be 123.  In the latter case, numbers should be undefined or just 0.

Comment: please exactly define your goal.Are you looking for getting numerical part on that string ?

Comment: I clarified my goal above.

Comment: I'd suggest spending more time reading up on basic JavaScript. For instance, you could raad about strings. Right away you'll discover different methods for manipulating strings, including `split`. Then, since `split` returns an array, you'll need to bone up on how to work with arrays, including accessing elements. If you don't make the investment in studying up on these things for yourself, you'll end up having to ask every single question on SO. "How do I make a string upper case?" Do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` and `parseInt` in this case:

```
var string_array = myString.split(" ");
var num = 0;
if ((string_array.length >= 2) && (string_array[0] === "foo"))
  num = parseInt(string_array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do in one line:

```
var num = parseFloat(("foo 12.3 14".match(/^foo (.+)/) || [,0])[1]);
```

Or maybe more readable in two:

```
var match = "foo 12.3 14".match(/^foo (.+)/),
    num = match ? parseFloat(match[1]) : 0;
```